# Как повернуть объект в сторону камеры только по оси Z?

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

Подскажите пожалуйста, как повернуть объект в сторону камеры только по одной оси.

Получается повернуть только когда *parent* (куб на скрине) вращаемого объекта на нуле.

```
// target - камера (шарик на скрине)

private void Update()
{
    var direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

    var euler = transform.eulerAngles;

    euler.z = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;

    transform.eulerAngles = euler;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Хотелось бы обойтись без LookRotation*

Comment: а можно узнать чем вам LookRotation не угодил? Вместо углов Эйлера, рекомендуется пользоваться кватернионами, иначе вы можете напороться на Gimbal lock. У кватернионов есть статические методы для оперирования поворотами очень удобные, посмотрите в их сторону

Comment: Дело в том, что это надо реализовать на другом движке у которого нет LookRotation, но так как он не популярен то я спрашивал по теме юнити

Comment: и все же лучше разобраться с кватернионами и делать через них. Это и проще будет, и неприятные неожиданности вроде  Gimbal lock будут не страшны. По сути углы эйлера это очередность поворотов по каждой оси выполненные в определенном порядке. Это подразумевает, что в одно состояние объект можно развернуть бесконечным числом способов.

Comment: С кватернионами все однозначней, там первые три координаты задают направление в котором смотрит forward объекта, а четвертая определяет его поворот вокруг своей оси, то бишь всего один вариант. Работая с углами Эйлера всегда есть вероятность что вы изменяете один из углов поворота и после манипуляций у вас резко меняются значения всех осей

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий вариант, но с *LookRotation*, может кому пригодится )

```
var angle = Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, transform.forward);
var direction = Camera.main.transform.forward - (transform.forward * angle);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, direction);
```

Comment: исходники `Quaternion` можно найти в сети легко